# Can I use Git to move files between svn repos with the history?

Tags: svn, git, data-migration

I've been using git-svn to work with svn repository A, and now I need to move the project over to repository B. I could just use svn to import the lastest HEAD from A. But I'd like to  preserve the history if there's a way. Is there a way to do this? Can I add repos b as a remote branch and dcommit to it or something? Not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You could using some special svn plugins for git but it's better to use Subversion's own tools for that.

The Subversion FAQ has an entry about this: [How do I merge two completely separate repositories?](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#multi-merge)

The simple dump/load way worked for me once quite well but I'd certainly suggest to create a backup before doing this merge.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that i don't have admin rights to use dump/load. I was hoping this way I could avoid having to get a sysadmin involved.

Comment: Without admin rights you can't freely set commit dates or authors in the past afaik. So you could only replay the commits in the same order and reset all commit authors to your account which is annoying in situations where you know "it worked a month ago" or want to blame another developer.

Answer (score 0):

In the [git svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) docs, there is a note for the `dcommit --commit-url` option (emphasis mine):

> This is intended to allow existing git svn repositories created with one transport method (e.g. `svn://` or `http://` for anonymous read) to be reused if a user is later given access to an alternate transport method (e.g. `svn+ssh://` or `https://`) for commit. **Using this option for any other purpose (don't ask) is very strongly discouraged.**

It's possible that you've discovered what the "don't ask" part of this is referring to.

Comment: Lol... How can the expect me to not try it when they put it what way?